# styled error action is not returned for ForbiddenHttpException in yii2

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii and I have the following code in some of the controllers that are only used for admin role.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            //'only' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update','delete'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

All attempts to this controller from non-admin roles are blocked as required but the styled yii's error action is not returned.
I have the following component in my main.php file:

```
'errorHandler' => [
      'errorAction' => 'main/error',
],
```

But it is not working, all I get is:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException: شما برای انجام این عملیات، دسترسی ندارید. in C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php:151
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php(134): yii\filters\AccessControl->denyAccess(Object(yii\web\User))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ActionFilter.php(75): yii\filters\AccessControl->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(545): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(272): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php(164): yii\base\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(154): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('error', Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(95): yii\base\Module->runAction('main/error')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException))
#10 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException))
#11 {main}
Previous exception:
yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException: شما برای انجام این عملیات، دسترسی ندارید. in C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php:151
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php(134): yii\filters\AccessControl->denyAccess(Object(yii\web\User))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ActionFilter.php(75): yii\filters\AccessControl->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(545): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(272): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php(164): yii\base\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(154): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(102): yii\base\Module->runAction('main/', Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\food\admin\web\index.php(20): yii\base\Application->run()
#11 {main}
```

Any guidance is appreciet.

Comment: I have renamed the default SiteController to MainController

Comment: Where is your error view saved? And post the MainController code

Comment: @Kyle It is saved in `views/main` directory, named: `error.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that to show the error page, I need to grant the permission of the error action to the non-admin users.

```
[
    'actions' => 
           ['logout', 'reset-password', 'request-password-reset', 'error'],
           'allow' => true,
           'roles' => ['branch'],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main controller you should have:

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I have it in my MainController :|